# jQuery Ajax post and response evaluation

Tags: jquery

I am relatively new to JavaScript and jQuery in particular, so please bear with me, I am trying to loop through multiple `<form>`s and then `serialize()` the data with jQuery and post it using Ajax to my page. This is happening alright, the data is posted, my PHP script echos 1 and everything is taken care off, but for some strange reason, the following code is not working, especially the "success" variable -- it's not increasing at all! What is wrong here?

```
$('.submitB').click(function(){

      var success = 0;
      var times = 0;
      var alertText;


  $('.input').each(function(){

      times++;

      var serializedForms = $(this).serialize();

      $.post('<?=$this->config->site_url()?>crud/additem/forms', serializedForms ,function(data){
          if (data)
          {
              success++;
          }
          });
  });

      if (times)
          {
              alertText = "تم إدخال " + success + " مدخل من إصل " + times + " بنجاح.";
              alert(alertText);
          }

})
```

(The Arabic text just says "`success` + Entries from + `times` + were entered successfully.")

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect any data to be returned?

It's look like `data == null`.

Comment: yes, my php script echos "1" if it's a success or "0" if it messed up, i'm using codeigniter as my framework and this code posted above is in the view, i tried it so many times with different jquery plugins and code that i wrote and it worked, but since i am posting multiple forms "rapidly" i think there might be a problem with jquery "jumping" code blocks? i apologize if i'm not making any sense but i am trying to give the full image